# Create an Update form using modal bootstrap and php

Tags: php, bootstrap-modal

I just want to create a update form by using modal but when i click the button update nothing happen no popup appear or did with a wrong ways? I already change the position of the end curly braces but still not working. Any ideas?

when i use the modal for add item it working nicely, can someone explain to me what i'm doing wrong whih modal

here is what I working on:

```html
<div class="card-block table-border-style">
   <div class="table-responsive">
      <table class="table table-hover">
         <thead>
            <tr>
               <th>#</th>
               <th>Name</th>
               <th>Status</th>
               <th>QR Code</th>
               <th>Update</th>
            </tr>
         </thead>
         <?
            include("../config_db/config_db_e.php");
            $quer1="SELECT * FROM info_kedai";
            $quer2=mysqli_query($db_conn_e,$quer1);
             while ($row= mysqli_fetch_array($quer2)){
               $id=$row["id_ke"];
               $name=$row["name_ke"];
               $status=$row["status_ke"];
            echo "<tbody>
                                                                
            <tr>
            <th>$id</th>
            <td>$name</td>
            <td>$status</td>
            <td><a href='qr_gen.php?id=$id'>Ganerate</a></td>
            <td>  <button type='button' class='btn btn-primary btn-outline-primary' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal2$id'>Edit</button></td>
            </tr>"; 
            }?>
         </tbody>
      </table>
   </div>
</div>
</div>
<!-- Hover table card end -->
</div>
<!-- Page-body end -->
</div>
</div>
<!-- Main-body end -->
<div id="styleSelector">
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<!-- Modal update  -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal2<?php echo $id ?>" role="dialog">
   <div class="modal-dialog">
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="modal-title">Update</h4>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-body">
            <form action="process/class_shop.php" method="GET">
               <?
                  $get=$row["id_kedai"];
                  $que1="SELECT * FROM info_kedai  where id_kedai='$get'";
                  $que2=mysqli_query($db_conn_e,$que1);
                  while ($row= mysqli_fetch_array($que2)){
                   
                      $id=$row["id_k"];
                      $name=$row["nama_k"];
                       $status=$row["status_k"];
                  ?>
               <label>Nama :</label><br>
               <input type="text" name="nama_k" id="nama_k" class="form-control" value="<? echo $name ?>"><br>
               <label>Status :</label><br>
               <select id="status_k" name="status_k" class="form-control" value="<? echo $status?>">
                  <option value="1">Aktif</option>
                  <option value="2">Not Aktif</option>
                  `enter code here`
               </select>
               <br><br>
               <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="update_k" id="update_k"  class="btn btn-primary btn-outline-primary">
               <?}?>
            </form>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: `class='btn btn-primary btn-outline-primary data-toggle=modal'` is missing two quotes `'`. One to separate `class` from `data-toggle` and one to open `data-toggle`

Comment: thanks, i already fix that but still not working

Comment: Because your modal `id` attribute is `id="myModal2<?php echo $id ?>"` and your button targets `data-target='#myModal2 $id'` - remove that space

Comment: @brombeer done but still the button not do anything

Comment: What version of Bootstrap? Any errors in your browser console? Are bootstrap css and javascript loaded correctly? Does the source code look ok? That code (with all the changes) looks fine to me, try reducing it/removing PHP stuff so that it works. Good luck